# Docker daemon is running but is unable to connect

Tags: docker

I'm trying to download a docker image with the following command

```
docker pull osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
```

But I get this error

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot 
connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.102:2376. Is the 
docker daemon running?). Using system default: 
https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.102:2376. Is 
the docker daemon running?
```

I've tried with restarting the docker service and with sudo.
I know the daemon is running becouse when I run "ps -A" there is a proccess named dockerd.

My docker version is 17.12.0-ce and I'm working on Ubuntu 17.04

Edit:

Output of ps -A, dockerd is at 31048

```
24036 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch
25083 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
25119 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
25895 ?        00:05:38 VBoxHeadless
28180 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1
28765 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:1
29057 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:1
29744 ?        00:00:04 chromium-browse
29799 ?        00:01:39 chromium-browse
30137 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:0
30879 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u8:1
30880 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0
30890 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:2
31048 ?        00:00:03 dockerd
31075 ?        00:00:02 docker-containe
31260 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy
31273 ?        00:00:00 docker-containe
31291 ?        00:00:00 run.sh
31336 ?        00:00:00 docker-containe
31353 ?        00:00:00 s6-svscan
31417 ?        00:00:00 s6-supervise
31418 ?        00:00:00 s6-supervise
31419 ?        00:00:00 s6-supervise
31421 ?        00:01:36 java
31465 ?        00:00:04 mysqld
31704 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:0
31800 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:1
31873 ?        00:00:01 rancher-catalog
31906 ?        00:00:02 websocket-proxy
```

Comment: Are you using docker machine, did you setup tls certificates, is there a `/var/run/docker.sock` file and is your user either root or in the docker group, and what does `env | grep DOCKER` output?

Answer (score 0):

The process is named **dockerd**, but you are calling it using **docker**.  Try the following

```
 dockerd pull osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, there was proxy configured in the environment variables which prevented dockerd from communicating with the virtual machine.